# using sqlite3 at child process issue

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

```
node-webkit : 0.12.3
IDE : webstorm 10
PC : win7 64bit
```

ChildProcess.js

```
var file = "./test.db";
var sql = require('../module/sqlite3').verbose();  // child process crash here
var db = new sql.Database(file);
db.close();
```

I don't understand what happens?

Others say node-webkit can't find node_sqlite3.node path.

I copied `"node_sqlite3.node"` from **"node-webkit-v0.12.3-win32-x64"** to **"node-v46-win32-x64"**.

But still not work.  Is something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

well sqlite3 has native codes in it so you need to compile it before using it.   follow this steps.

```
$ npm install node-pre-gyp
```

cd in node_modules/sqlite3 then

```
$ node-pre-gyp build --runtime=node-webkit --target=x.xx.x  (your version)
```

i.e copying the .node file won't work